# Splitting in Python with everything BUT particular set of cases

Tags: python, string, split

I am not very good with regex and it continues to confuse me every time it comes up so instead of writing a possibly incorrect regex string, I want to split a string a different way.

Let's say I have a string "hello, my name is Joseph! Haha, hello!" and I want to split it whenever I encounter a non-alphanumeric character. So then, in this case, I would obtain:

"hello"
"my"
"name"
"is"
"Joseph"
"Haha"
"hello"

Is there a way to do this without a regex string? As in: split whenever character != alphanumeric?

(Yes, I do realize it is probably not a smart thing to do to not correct my regex deficiency!)

Comment: Well, I do not see any problem with using a very simple, straightforward regex here, `re.split(r'\W+', s)`, or another one, `re.findall(r'\w+', s)`

Comment: or just s.split() gets you ['hello,', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Joseph!', 'Haha,', 'hello!'], which you can fix pretty easily. Or s.replace("!"," ").split, which gives ['hello,', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Joseph', 'Haha,', 'hello']

Comment: Yes, there are probably a few ways of doing it. Will it make it more readable or a better approach by not using regex? Probably not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I think it is appropriate to use simple and straightforward regexes for such simple tasks.

Compare an *itertools* and *re* solutions:

```
import itertools, re
s = "hello, my name is Joseph! Haha, hello!"
print(["".join(x) for _, x in itertools.groupby(s, key=str.isalnum)][0::2])
print(re.findall(r"\w+", s))
```

See an [online Python demo here](http://ideone.com/PVr3y1).

As for me, I'd vote for the regex here. The `\w+` matches one or more word characters (letters, digits, underscores) and the `re.findall` returns all the non-overlapping occurrences.

The itertools `groupby` groups the substring chunks according to the `key` which is set to alphanumeric (`str.alnum`) and all the even tokens (the non-word chunks in this concrete case) are removed from the final result with `[0::2]`. If a string starts with a non-word char, this won't work, a regex solution is safer and easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always glad when someone tries to [avoid using
regex](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)
;) But here it's probably the best tool for the job.

You can write your own parser, but that is much more verbose:

```
s = "hello, my name is Joseph! Haha, hello!"
words = []
lasti = 0
lastp = False
for i,p in enumerate (not c.isalpha() for c in s):
    if p != lastp:
        if p: words.append (s[lasti:i])
        lasti, lastp = i,p

print (', '.join (words))
```